# Perl CPAN module download fails

Tags: perl, cpan

The download for the 'App-xml_grep2-0.14.tar.gz' `perl` module continually fails for me.

`cpan http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/MI/MIROD/App-xml_grep2-0.14.tar.gz`

```
Please login with USER and PASS

Passive mode off.
Please login with USER and PASS.
ftp: bind: Address already in use
```

Comment: Before going this route, make sure the module isn't available already as a package by your distribution. It is better to have the package management system keep track (and update, and ...) of stuff. Doing it by hand doesn't scale very far.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of giving `cpan` a URL, give a module name:

```
$ sudo cpan App::Xml_grep2
```

The only reasons I can think of to give a URL instead is if your module lives outside the CPAN directory, or you need a specific older version, rather than the current version.

I also find it odd that `cpan` is using FTP when you gave it an HTTP URL. I don't know why that is, but that leads you to the real problem, which is that it looks like it's trying active FTP and failing, probably because of a firewall that only works with passive FTP. The way out of this trap is to [force `cpan` to use passive FTP](http://perl-begin.org/topics/cpan/life-with-cpan/).